# How to fetch multi data in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

in my `react` application i want to use multi `fetch` in `useEffect` but, they not working just first function works!.

code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getInfo = async () => {
      try {
        const user = await transitionData(
          `http://localhost:5000/user/${authContext.userId}/profile?t=user`,
          "GET",
          null,
          { Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}` }
        );

        const posts = await transitionData(
          `http://localhost:5000/user/${authContext.userId}/profile?t=posts`,
          "GET",
          null,
          { Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}` }
        );

        const savedPosts = await transitionData(
          `http://localhost:5000/user/${authContext.userId}/profile?t=saved`,
          "GET",
          null,
          { Authorization: `Bearer ${authContext.token}` }
        );

        setUser(user);
        setPosts(posts);
        setSaved(savedPosts);
      } catch (error) {}
    };

    getInfo();
  }, [transitionData, authContext.userId, authContext.token]);
```

Comment: not sure if it would solve the issue , but the way you are making requests in not the best . You are blocking the code which doesnt need to block . rather than `(const user = await transitionData())`just do `(const user = transitionData)`...and then  use `await Promise.all([user,posts,savedPosts])`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11751174/ankush-verma Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did all of the functions run?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11751174/ankush-verma Yeah. all of them can work

Comment: Okay . weird though.